# SVG sprite in CSS content attribute

Tags: css, svg

I have a given svg-sprite:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
   <symbol id="envelope" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
      <path d="M502.3 190.8c3.9-3.1 ...."></path>
   </symbol>
   <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50" id="menu-2">
     <path d="M0 3h50v2H0zm0 14h50v2H0zm0 14h50v2H0zm0 14h50v2H0z"></path>
   </symbol>
</svg>
```

Now i would like to add the second symbol (menu-2) to the ":after" of mydiv

```
mydiv:after {
   content: url("somehow add menu-2 from svg sprite");
}
```

How can i reference it?

Answer (score 2):

```
mydiv:after {
   content: url(http://server/sprite.svg#menu-2);
}
```

where -

`http://server` path to the server or to the folder where the svg file is stored
`#menu-2` - The called part of the sprite